# Trigger TypeAhead suggestion selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, capybara, typeahead.js

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to trigger a suggestion selection on a `TypeAhead` input

I've tried all kinds of things like

```
.trigger('suggestionClicked', $('.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion:nth-child(1)'))
```

I suppose there are really two parts to this problem.

**1. Properly selecting the actual TypeAhead object.**

I do this primarily by focusing (`focus()`) on the input field, and then using jQuery to find the element that is active (`$(document.activeElement)`). This might not be the best way. It's quite difficult to test in the browser web-inspector because every time I go to the console I lose focus and then the menu disappears (literally removing the results from the DOM)

**2. Triggering the correct event.**

I'm not sure exactly on which object or which event to trigger, but my best guess is either `suggestionClicked` on either the `TypeAhead` object or the `TypeAhead.Dropdown` object. Second best guess would be `click.tt`.

I might be overthinking this.

If you really care about the reason behind this, it's because I need to test the functionality via Capybara/Selenium.

I've been **[browsing the source code](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/dist/typeahead.bundle.js#L1242)** on github for some insight.

Here is a step in my Capybara attempt. I feel like I'm getting close but it's not there yet.

steps.rb

```
Then /^I select result number "([^\"]*)" from typeahead$/ do |num|
  find('.tt-dropdown-menu')
  #within('.tt-dropdown-menu') do
    page.execute_script %Q{$(document.activeElement).dropdown().trigger('suggestionClicked', $('.tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion:nth-child(#{num})'))}
  #end
end
```

Comment: If you inspect the element in the DOM there shouldn't be a need to go into the inspector (it should snap to the element you are looking for).  Try clicking the magnifying glass in the inspector in Chrome.  That might help find the element you need just by hovering over it.